# New project Xcode with a git repo

Tags: xcode, git, project

I have a project on my git repo and i want to use it with Xcode but when i create a new project and do the check out the files are just downloaded but they are not include to my Xcode project.

How to do this ?

Comment: This might help you. http://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not my problem... I need to check out those files to my Xcode project and to be able compile it and use it. When i add the check out files manualy they are not depending to my project